# including baseline value for outcome in multi level logistic regression

Tags: logistic, sas

I am trying to predict poor vs. high self rated health in a multi-national survey with complex sampling. I have two time points and I am using proc glimmix in SAS with cluster and sample weights. All of my covariates are recorded at baseline, and my outcome is at follow up. When I add baseline self rated health (as a dichotomous var) at time 1, the model does not converge. Could this be because there is not enough variation between baseline and follow up self rated health?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that (if covariates seem to perfectly "explain" the outcome) would be an obvious problem.